# Jenkins docker slave configuration Error: SSH service hadn't started after 43 seconds

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins docker slave and execute the Jenkin's job, But I'm getting `java.io.IOException: SSH service hadn't started after 43 seconds` error when I executed the job and the job is stuck in the pending state.

[image]

On the docker host, the image has been pulled and the docker container started but after a few seconds, it is disappearing.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
4d5ce59aaf97        someone/jenkins-docker-slave:1.0   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D -…"   41 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       0.0.0.0:32771->22/tcp   lucid_hypatia
```

Can someone help me how to resolve this error

Comment: Try to increase the ssh connection timeout of the machine. If you are using Linux, please refer to this https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/ This helped me earlier to solve this issue.